# UIDocumentPickerViewController vs iCloud Drive app container?

Tags: ios, icloud-drive, uidocumentpickervc

- The app's container is public, so it is visible in iCloud Drive.
- The app displays files in its public iCloud container.
- The app can I also present the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` with `UIDocumentPickerModeImport` mode so users can import files from other containers.

But I do not want users to be able to import files from the app's own container. These are already visible in the app using `NSMetadataQuery`.

How can I prevent this?

- The container must be public so it is visible from iCloud Drive on the desktop. So hiding it is not an option.
- I could use `UIDocumentPickerModeOpen` instead, because then I can examine the fileURL and see that the selected item is within the app's container.
- I was hoping I could create an `NSMetadataQuery` from the url given by the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and then check the `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsExternalDocumentKey` attribute. But I haven't managed to do that.